# Crystal report is not printing all pages using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have created a web project with crystal report. When I am printing any document with more than one pages it is not printing all pages. It is printing only current page. 
Here is my javascript print code.

```
function Print() {
            var dvReport = document.getElementById("dvReport");
            var frame1 = dvReport.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
            if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Internet Explorer") != -1 || navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Trident") != -1) {
                frame1.name = frame1.id;
                window.frames[frame1.id].focus();
                window.frames[frame1.id].print();
            }
            else {
                var frameDoc = frame1.contentWindow ? frame1.contentWindow : frame1.contentDocument.document ? frame1.contentDocument.document : frame1.contentDocument;
                frameDoc.print();
                        }                        
            return false;
        }
```

Please help guys

Answer (score -1):

SeparatePages="False" at crystalreport viewer

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Normally this sound be a comment, I know that you still cannot comment, please be patient! In your answer try to be more informative. Where do you think this change should be done? See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer